# May JavaFX 2.0 be redistributed?

Tags: licensing, javafx

I'm currently planning to develop a desktop Java application that I might want to distribute in the future. As for the UI technology, I thought about JavaFX, since Swing won't be developed any further and JavaFX seems to have some nice properties.

I know that it'll still take a while for JavaFX to be available on more platforms but I assume once it is available on Linux by the end of 2012 it should be fine.

Since I want the requirements for my app to be as low as possible and installation as smooth as possible I'd like to redistribute the JavaFX runtime along with the app. The only requirement for the app to run should be an existing JRE.

However, I'm a bit confused on whether I'm allowed to redistribute the JavaFX runtime or not.

[Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/documentation/default-494799.html) says:

> Redistributing the JavaFX Runtime is not allowed as per the terms and conditions in the License Agreement.

Whereas [JavaFX.com](http://javafx.com/faq/) suggests:

> Several deployment options are available for application developers who want to make the JavaFX Runtime installation as smooth as possible for end users:
>
> - Redistribute the JavaFX Runtime tightly integrated with your Java application.

Does anyone know which is true or maybe what the differences are (when am I allowed to redistribute the runtime, when not) ?

Comment: "Swing won't be developed any further". Really? Do you have a link for that?

Comment: @Thilo at least that's what the Oracly guys said at Devox, I don't have link right now. Maybe it's expressed a bit confusingly, what I mean is that Oracle seems to view JavaFX as the future GUI framework and put most of their efforts into that rather than Swing. - Btw, that isn't the point, I just wanted to give some reasons why I consider JavaFX in order to prevent "use Swing" style comments. The actual question is on the licensing which would influence my decision.

Comment: @Thilo: A bit late, but today, [there is authoritative info about that](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#6)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: @Pang I agree, it is off-topic as of the current definition of scope. Since the question is 3.5 years old, answered and somewhat outdated anyways, it's fine with me to have this closed. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With today's 2.0.2 release License was updated to allow redistribution: http://javafx.com/faq/#10

> Starting with JavaFX 2.0.2, JavaFX is available under the same license and business model as Java SE. This includes the ability to distribute the JavaFX Runtime (or SDK) for third party developers with their application(s), subject to the terms and conditions of the license.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info.

Comment: Does this include the option to distribute my application with the FX runtime .jar and the appropriate licenses and readmes (as I would with any other library), or am I limited to adding a copy of the FX runtime installer to my software?

Comment: @UrsReupke, did you ever receive an answer to your question here? I'm wondering if it's legal to freely use JavaFX and redistribute the runtime too, if I use JavaFX in a commercial application (that I sell to customers). Is this allowed? It seems so

Comment: Sorry, @Mathomatic, I never got an answer here or elsewhere. At one point, I just decided to bundle the JRE with my app, that's certainly legal.