# In what form may JavaFX 2.0.2 be redistributed?

Tags: licensing, javafx-2

As I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372217/may-javafx-2-0-be-redistributed), Java FX 2.0.2 may be redistributed according to [these terms](http://javafx.com/faq/#10).

Does this include the option to distribute my application with the FX runtime .jar and the appropriate licenses and readmes (as I would with any other library), or am I limited to adding a copy of the FX runtime installer to my software?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you comply with the clauses [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html) (in particular clause C), you should be able to bundle the complete JavaFX runtime for a given target operating system (jar, readmes, licenses and native code) with your application.

Indeed, in a discussion on JavaFX deployment options, Richard Bair, head of Java Client development at Oracle [noted](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2011-December/000413.html) that [in many contexts] "The solution I like best is one where you co-bundle Java + FX with your application as a single executable."  Though, as JavaFX 2.0.2 has it's own installer, this single executable bundling option might only be available in later releases.

If you have specific questions or concerns you should contact Oracle directly to make sure that your proposed usage of the software and distribution method will conform to the license agreement.

Comment: That's it. I just wasn't sure was "complete and unmodified form" in clause C referred to.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you need to be aware of is that from Java 7 Update 4 then the JDK will ship with JavaFX bundled automatically.

So you should be careful to make sure that there won't be clashes between the system JavaFX libs and your bundled ones on JDKs later that 7u4.

Comment: According to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html, it is bundled with Java 7 after update 2.

Comment: Yes, but that's 2.0.2, which is Windows-only.

Comment: Yes, of course. I didn't know 7u4 will be for all OSs.

Comment: GA for Windows and Mac, a pretty decent Developer Preview for Linux