# JavaFX license - is including javaFX jar on your app server not breaching the license?

Tags: jar, licensing, installation, javafx

So I've got an application which starts via Java WebStart. It requires javafx jar to work properly. If  I place the javaFX jar on my server (so that it could be downloaded when starting the application) would it be ok with the license?

Comment: Ok, seems I found the answer here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372217/may-javafx-2-0-be-redistributed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the license (it should be possibe to provide native bundles which include the jre + javafx), but for Java WebStart the recommended way is to install the latest JRE on client-side, which comes with JavaFX. So you don't need the javafx jar on the server.

You should include the JavaFX start classes in the main jar, however, and have the correct JavaFX Manifest entries. But since the JavaFX Ant task provided by Oracle is copying these start classes to the main jar, I guess it's ok to use them. But I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: Installing the JRE on client side is not an option, client will have to use Java 6.

Comment: It's recommended to use Java SE 7 as Java SE 6 reaches End-of-Life this month. Or make sure you have the necessary support contracts with Oracle. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#5